# List.Add Performance issue

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios

I have the following code:

```
foreach(Icon item in iconObjects) 
{ 
    iconList.Add(item.iconID); //iconID is a GUID string 
}
```

I'm finding 197 records. It takes ~10 seconds to execute the loop and populate the list. Any thoughts on improving the performance?

I've tried:

```
iconList.AddRange(iconObjects.Select(y=> y.iconID))
```

But it takes the same amount of time.

Thanks, 
Rick

Comment: How large are those strings?  Are you running into heap LOH fragmentation? Use a profiler and/or run some simple tests (i.e., try adding 197 `int`s and see what the difference is. Guessing is a waste of time.

Comment: @EdS. "GUID strings", so they should be <100 characters.

Comment: @delnan: I assume nothing :).  Specifically, I do not assume that everyone who uses the term "GUID" is using it correctly.

Comment: What are the types for `iconObjects` and `iconList` ? They don't sounds like `List<T>` and are where the time is being spent (fetching or adding).

Comment: iconObjects is a CSList object - a list of db objects (records). I think they are lazy loaded, so the idea that the problem is in data retrieval seems like a good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the `List` shouldn't take that long for 197 items. Most likely it's taking so long because `iconObjects` is an iQueryable or iEnumerable.

Why not do a

```
var iconList = iconObjects.ToList();
```

Time this, and you should see that the expensive call is when it's actually retrieving the data, and not adding to the list.